# I want to center the elements of a footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a footer with 3 elements.

1. © 2020, The Mixdown Bible (text)
2. ¿Quiénes somos? (text)
3. Instagram logo (png) and Facebook logo (png)

The problem is that the space that "1)" occupies is longer than "3)".
I want "2)" to be completely centered, not just relatively centered to the space between "1)" and "3)"

This is what I've tried:

```
<footer>
        <hr>
        <div class="footer_container">
            <p>© 2020, The Mixdown Bible</p>
            <p>¿Quiénes somos?</p>
            <div class="redes_container">
                <a href="/"><img src="imagenes/redes/instagram.png"></a>
                <a href="/"><img src="imagenes/redes/facebook.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

```
*
{box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

footer
{margin-top: 60px;
margin-bottom: 40px;}

hr
{background-color: #6A6A6A;
height: 1px;}

.footer_container
{margin-left: 22%;
margin-right: 22%;
margin-top: 40px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;}

footer p
{font-family: "Poppins";
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 14px;
color: #6A6A6A;}

.redes_container
{display: inline-flex;}

.redes_container img
{width: 50%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using css grid instead of flexbox
.footer-container {
display: grid;
grid-template columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr
}
This way the 3 divs would take the same space